# Definition of a static variable inside a parallel region

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, static, openmp

I have a parallel region, I have a static variable defined inside this region, like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    static int var;
    // some stuff
}
```

Without `threadprivate`, static variables are shared between threads, so there is actually one instance seen by all the threads. [This source](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2020/01/02/static-variable-initialization/#the-two-stages-of-static-variable-initialization) says *static initialization happens first and usually at compile time*. What happens in this case? Does the compiler just ignore this parallel region for the static variable and treat it as if it had been placed outside the parallel region?

Comment: That 'source' is misleading. [This source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (a Draft C++ Standard) says: *Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration.*

Comment: @AdrianMole doesn't control passing happen during compilation?

Comment: How can it? That 'control' a run-time thing.

Comment: @AdrianMole clear, and what about the question itself?

Comment: @AdrianMole I found [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) saying _If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once)_. It is just sometimes you are not experienced enough to know what exactly to look for :)